# Filter inner ng-repeat based on values in outer ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

In the code below, I want to display the distinct tags, then for each tag I would like to filter the values in the inner ng-repeat. Is this possible? or do I have to create a separate array of distinct tags?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-init="servers = [
      {name:'UK001', os:'win 2008', tag:'prod'},
      {name:'UK002', os:'win 2008', tag:'prod'},
      {name:'UK003', os:'win 2003', tag:'Dev'},
      {name:'UK004', os:'win 2008', tag:'Dev'}
    ]">

        <div  ng-repeat="server in servers ">
            <h1> {{tag}}</h1>
           <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="server in servers | filter : {tag :server.tag } ">
                    <h3>{{server.name}} {{server.os}} </h3>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything is going to get repeated multiple times with this method.

Comment: I would like to group the servers under the Tags. I guess I have to create a separate "distinct" array of tags as my outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lhTmyp7BEtHGfJD2LFKr

#### You should create tags object like so:

```
var servers = [
    {name:'UK001', os:'win 2008', tag:'prod'},
    {name:'UK002', os:'win 2008', tag:'prod'},
    {name:'UK003', os:'win 2003', tag:'Dev'},
    {name:'UK004', os:'win 2008', tag:'Dev'}
];

$scope.tags = servers.reduce(function(tags,server){

  var tag = server.tag;

  if(! tags[tag] ) tags[tag] = [];

  delete server.tag; // we don't need it anymore

  tags[tag].push(server);

  return tags;
},{});
```

#### Now, you can iterate that object like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(tag, servers) in tags ">
  <h1> {{tag}}</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="server in servers">
        <h3>{{server.name}} {{server.os}} </h3>
    </li>      
</div>
```

---

The JSON representation of the tags object:

```
{
  "prod": [
    {
      "name": "UK001",
      "os": "win 2008"
    },
    {
      "name": "UK002",
      "os": "win 2008"
    }
  ],
  "Dev": [
    {
      "name": "UK003",
      "os": "win 2003"
    },
    {
      "name": "UK004",
      "os": "win 2008"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ilan, I am not able to see the Plunker link, I guess I need to have an account.